# How do I manipulate this expression to isolate variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For referrence:

$X(1-1)\cdot Y(1-2)$

can be expressed as

$(X\cdot Y) (1-1) \cdot (1-2)$

How can I do the same (isolating X, Y)
with this expression?

$\dfrac{X (1-1)}{Y(1-2)}$

Comment: There is a problem in your question. In the last expression, is the $(1-\delta 2)$ in the numerator or denominator of the fraction? According to the normal order of operations, it would be in the numerator, but I doubt that is what you mean. If you plan to continue asking questions on this site you should [learn and use MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which will make your questions much more clear.

Comment: I made some edits to hopefully make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you, you want

$$\frac{X (1-\delta 1)}{Y(1-\delta 2)} = \left(\frac XY\right) \cdot \left(\frac{1-\delta 1}{1-\delta 2}\right)$$